# Time Series Data Reformat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, string-to-datetime

I am working on some code that will rearrange a time series. Currently I have a standard time series. I have a three columns with with the header being [Date, Time, Value]. I want to reformat the  dataframe to index with the date and use a header with the time (i.e. 0:00, 1:00, ... , 23:00). The dataframe will be filled in with the value.

Here is the Dataframe currently have

[image: output]

[image]

essentially I'd like to mve the index toa single day and show the hours through the columns.

Thanks,

Comment: Will you please provide your data as text, not an image? I can't copy/paste from an image.

Comment: Yes let me try and figure out how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot`:

```
df = df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Time', values='Total')
```

Output (first 10 columns and with random values for `Total`):

```
>>> df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Time', values='Total').iloc[0:10]
time        00:00:00  01:00:00  02:00:00  03:00:00  04:00:00  05:00:00  06:00:00  07:00:00  08:00:00  09:00:00
date                                                                                                          
2019-01-01  0.732494  0.087657  0.930405  0.958965  0.531928  0.891228  0.664634  0.432684  0.009653  0.604878
2019-01-02  0.471386  0.575126  0.509707  0.715290  0.337983  0.618632  0.413530  0.849033  0.725556  0.186876
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.
Split the time part to get only the hour. Add `hr` to it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-01-01', '00:00:00',-127.57],['2019-01-01', '01:00:00',-137.57],['2019-01-02', '00:00:00',-147.57],], columns=['Date', 'Time', 'Totals'])
df['hours'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: 'hr'+ str(int(x.split(':')[0])))
print(pd.pivot_table(df, values ='Totals', index=['Date'], columns = 'hours'))
```

**Output**

```
hours          hr0     hr1
Date                      
2019-01-01 -127.57 -137.57
2019-01-02 -147.57     NaN
```